# How to improve archiving data to Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure

I have a need to archive data from a SQL Server database to a Azure storage container blob.

The data is retrieved by a stored procedure (basically return all data which is older than n days). There are about 1.4 million rows of data which need to be saved to a blob in Azure.

The process takes quite a while to complete so is there a way I can speed this up? A C# console application is used to retrieve the data and upload it to Azure. Here is the relevant code.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("snip");
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("core-backups");
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("2017/04/26/data.txt");

var data = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("snip"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand getOldLogData = new SqlCommand("backup_sp", conn);
    getOldLogData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    getOldLogData.CommandTimeout = 300;
    getOldLogData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Days", 30);
    using (SqlDataAdapter adr = new SqlDataAdapter(getOldLogData))
    {
        adr.Fill(data);
    }
}

using (var writeStream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
    {
        data.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
}
```

The file saved in Azure is 540 MB, so I am looking for a way to make the upload to Azure more efficient, and also if possible how to compress the data so the filesize is smaller? We may in the future want to restore the data which is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to Upload the file with better performance you need to set the `CloudBlobClient.ParallelOperationThreadCount` on the blobClient to a higher number. This will upload the file in different threads. You can see in fiddler how the file is sent.

You can read more about it here :: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.paralleloperationthreadcount

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/avkashchauhan/2012/02/21/windows-azure-blob-upload-scenarios/

2) Apart from this you might want to gzip the file to reduce the file size but you will have to compress/uncompress it everytime.

3) Another option is, if this is an offline process you can use the AzCopy exe from microsoft to upload the file. You can read more about it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy